# Java: Trouble in computing the root of a given polynomial

Tags: java, arrays, function, for-loop, polynomials

I'm trying to enter a for-loop over a subinterval that forms a partition of another within a specified range in order to calculate the roots of a given polynomial.  My problem is that my "if" and "if-else" are not executed, even when conditions should ensure their execution.  I've tested my "poly" function in other parts of the program and found no issues.  Here is my troublesome for-loop.

```
for (int i = L; i < R; i += resolution) {
       double a = i, b = resolution+i;
       { if (poly(C, a)*poly(C, b) < 0) {
          double mid = findRoot(C, a, b, tolerance);
          System.out.println(mid);
          if (Math.abs(poly(C, mid)) < threshold){
            System.out.println("Root found at: "+mid);
            numCount = 1;
          }
       } else if (poly(D, a)*poly(D, b) < 0) {
          double mid = findRoot(D, a, b, tolerance);
          if(Math.abs(poly(C, mid)) < threshold) {
            System.out.println("Root found at: "+mid);
            numCount = 2;

       } else {
         numCount = 3;
         System.out.println("No roots were found in the specified range.");
       } System.out.println("numCount is "+numCount); break;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove the set of brackets that starts immediately before the word "if."

Comment: Thank you!  I've fixed the bracket mishap, but now encountered a new problem with the source code preceding the for-loop.  I want to assign L and R using the Scanner class, i.e. L =scanner.nextInt() and R=scanner.nextInt().  The input stream is not closing after assignment and therefore not entering the for-loop:                                                              System.out.println("Enter the Left and Right endpoints: ");
     L = sc.nextInt();
     R = sc.nextInt();

for (int i = L; i < R; i++) { // code}

Answer (score 0):

You have a redundant set of brackets that should be removed. These bracket make the `else if` and `else` clauses apply to the inner `if`, which is incorrect:

```
for (int i = L; i < R; i += resolution) {
   double a = i, b = resolution+i;
   if (poly(C, a)*poly(C, b) < 0) {
      double mid = findRoot(C, a, b, tolerance);
      System.out.println(mid);
      if (Math.abs(poly(C, mid)) < threshold){
        System.out.println("Root found at: "+mid);
        numCount = 1;
      }
   } else if (poly(D, a)*poly(D, b) < 0) {
      double mid = findRoot(D, a, b, tolerance);
      if(Math.abs(poly(C, mid)) < threshold) {
        System.out.println("Root found at: "+mid);
        numCount = 2;

   } else {
     numCount = 3;
     System.out.println("No roots were found in the specified range.");
   } 
   System.out.println("numCount is "+numCount); break;
}
```

Comment: I've fixed the bracket mishap, but now encountered a new problem with the source code preceding the for-loop.  The input stream closing                           System.out.println("Enter the Left and Right endpoints: ");
     L = sc.nextInt();
     R = sc.nextInt();